# How to access any web site using IP:Port?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I have One windows 2008 R2 server. I have installed website that is running fine. Now I have installed Website Panel this is opening like IP:9001 with in server. But When I trying to open that url from outside this is not opening. In that same IP my one website is running fine outside.

Please suggest me how do i d o the setting that I an access one website IP:PORT like that from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure an port forwarding on the router thats between the inside and the outside. There should already be a rule for port 80 otherwise your site shouldnt work from outside